# How to use RESTful Web Services from iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, rest

I followed the guide to doing RESTful for iOS from the following link from start to finish, but doesn't seem to fetch any data from the NSURL provided.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-ios/

What may be the issue? Can't seem to find any. Any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The guidance can be given if you put your code, so we can see what is wrong with it..

Comment: @are you want to use AFNetworking then will helps you. because i have very easy and simple methods which calls your all rest APIs easily and fast.